# Why does the MultipleAnswer[z] doesn't get set to the Intermediary's value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to set the `multipleAnswer[z]`  value as intermediary arrays content but it seems not to do anything. I have tried printing out the values of every step of the code and it seems to fail at this assignment. The code collects answers from the page and aggregates it to two arrays `Answer` and `multipleAnswer`.

```js
document.getElementById("SubmitButton").onclick = function(e) {
    let Answer = [];
    let multipleAnswer = [];
    e.preventDefault();
    const questionCounter = questions.length;
    var z = 0;
    for (x in questions) {
        const radioGroup = document.getElementById("answers" + z + "");
        const selectedValue = radioGroup.value;
        let multipleAnswerIntermediary = [];
        if (questions[x]["multipleCorrectAnswers"]) {

            for (y in questions[x]["answers"][z]) {
                const multipleAnswerSelector = document.getElementById("multipleanswer" + questions[x]["id"] + "a" + y)
                const multipleAnswerValue = multipleAnswerSelector.checked;
                multipleAnswerIntermediary[y] = multipleAnswerValue;
                console.log(multipleAnswer[z])
                console.log(multipleAnswerIntermediary)

            }
            multipleAnswer[z] = multipleAnswerIntermediary;

            console.log(multipleAnswer[z])
        }
        console.log(multipleAnswer[z])
        Answer[z] = selectedValue;
        z = z + 1;

        console.log(z)
        console.log(selectedValue)

        console.log(Answer[z])
        console.log(questions[x])
        console.log(Answer)

    }
}
```

HTML is generated by another piece of JS but here is an example.

```
        
        
      <sl-card class="kortele card-header card-footer" style="clear:both; --width: 0px;">
        <div slot="header" class="korteles-headeris" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; font-weight: 500; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
  <div>
    Question <strong style="font-weight: 400; font-size: var(--sl-font-size-large);">1</strong>/<sub style="font-size: var(--sl-font-size-medium); font-weight: 400;">4</sub>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size: var(--sl-font-size-medium); font-weight: 400;">
    Points: <strong>20</strong>
  </div>
</div>

            <div class="question-list">
              <div class="question-column">
                <h3>What are the correct steps of Risk Management?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="question-column">
                <ul id="answerstext0">
                <li><strong>A</strong>: Identify, evaluate, prioritize, minimize, control &amp; monitor risk</li><li><strong>B</strong>: Evaluate, prioritize, identify, minimize, control &amp; monitor risk</li><li><strong>C</strong>: Control &amp; monitor, minimize, identify, prioritize, evaluate risk</li><li><strong>D</strong>: Prioritize, identify, minimize, evaluate, control &amp; monitor risk</li></ul>
                </div>
              </div>


          <div slot="footer">
            <sl-radio-group id="answers0" name="a" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; " value="" form="" data-optional="" data-valid="">
            
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="0" value="0" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--first sl-button-group__button--radio">A</sl-radio-button>
        
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="0" value="1" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--inner sl-button-group__button--radio">B</sl-radio-button>
        
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="0" value="2" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--inner sl-button-group__button--radio">C</sl-radio-button>
        
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="0" value="3" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--last sl-button-group__button--radio">D</sl-radio-button>
        </sl-radio-group>
          <div class="multipleanswers" id="multipleanswers0">
          </div>
          </div>
        </sl-card>
      <sl-card class="kortele card-header card-footer" style="clear:both; --width: 0px;">
        <div slot="header" class="korteles-headeris" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; font-weight: 500; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
  <div>
    Question <strong style="font-weight: 400; font-size: var(--sl-font-size-large);">2</strong>/<sub style="font-size: var(--sl-font-size-medium); font-weight: 400;">4</sub>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size: var(--sl-font-size-medium); font-weight: 400;">
    Points: <strong>20</strong>
  </div>
</div>

            <div class="question-list">
              <div class="question-column">
                <h3>What are the goals of Risk Management?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="question-column">
                <ul id="answerstext1">
                <li><strong>A</strong>: Radiation resistance</li><li><strong>B</strong>: Turning tiny</li><li><strong>C</strong>: lLiLli blast</li></ul>
                </div>
              </div>


          <div slot="footer">
            <sl-radio-group id="answers1" name="a" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; " value="" form="" data-optional="" data-valid="">
            
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="1" value="0" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--first sl-button-group__button--radio">A</sl-radio-button>
        
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="1" value="1" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--inner sl-button-group__button--radio">B</sl-radio-button>
        
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="1" value="2" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--last sl-button-group__button--radio">C</sl-radio-button>
        </sl-radio-group>
          <div class="multipleanswers" id="multipleanswers1">
          </div>
          </div>
        </sl-card>
      <sl-card class="kortele card-header card-footer" style="clear:both; --width: 0px;">
        <div slot="header" class="korteles-headeris" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; font-weight: 500; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
  <div>
    Question <strong style="font-weight: 400; font-size: var(--sl-font-size-large);">3</strong>/<sub style="font-size: var(--sl-font-size-medium); font-weight: 400;">4</sub>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size: var(--sl-font-size-medium); font-weight: 400;">
    Points: <strong>20</strong>
  </div>
</div>

            <div class="question-list">
              <div class="question-column">
                <h3>Multiple correct answers?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="question-column">
                <ul id="answerstext2">
                <li><strong>A</strong>: Radiation resistance</li><li><strong>B</strong>: Turning tiny</li><li><strong>C</strong>: lLiLli blast</li></ul>
                </div>
              </div>


          <div slot="footer">
            <sl-radio-group id="answers2" name="a" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; " value="" form="" data-optional="" data-valid="">
            </sl-radio-group>
          <div class="multipleanswers" id="multipleanswers2">
          
        <sl-checkbox id="multipleanswer2a0" size="medium" form="" data-optional="" data-valid="">A</sl-checkbox>
        
        <sl-checkbox id="multipleanswer2a1" size="medium" form="" data-optional="" data-valid="">B</sl-checkbox>
        
        <sl-checkbox id="multipleanswer2a2" size="medium" form="" data-optional="" data-valid="">C</sl-checkbox>
        </div>
          </div>
        </sl-card>
      <sl-card class="kortele card-header card-footer" style="clear:both; --width: 0px;">
        <div slot="header" class="korteles-headeris" style="display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; font-weight: 500; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">
  <div>
    Question <strong style="font-weight: 400; font-size: var(--sl-font-size-large);">4</strong>/<sub style="font-size: var(--sl-font-size-medium); font-weight: 400;">4</sub>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size: var(--sl-font-size-medium); font-weight: 400;">
    Points: <strong>20</strong>
  </div>
</div>

            <div class="question-list">
              <div class="question-column">
                <h3>What is happening two?</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="question-column">
                <ul id="answerstext3">
                <li><strong>A</strong>: Radiation resistance</li><li><strong>B</strong>: Turning tiny</li><li><strong>C</strong>: lLiLli blast</li></ul>
                </div>
              </div>


          <div slot="footer">
            <sl-radio-group id="answers3" name="a" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; " value="" form="" data-optional="" data-valid="">
            
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="3" value="0" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--first sl-button-group__button--radio">A</sl-radio-button>
        
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="3" value="1" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--inner sl-button-group__button--radio">B</sl-radio-button>
        
        <sl-radio-button pill="" size="medium" name="3" value="2" role="presentation" class="sl-button-group__button sl-button-group__button--last sl-button-group__button--radio">C</sl-radio-button>
        </sl-radio-group>
          <div class="multipleanswers" id="multipleanswers3">
          </div>
          </div>
        </sl-card>
```

Comment: Please add html as well

Comment: At its current status it's impossible to say anything, because half of the things you use in this code are not defined or are part of an HTML you don't show.

Comment: Added the HTML.